# Real structure on algberaic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algberaic group defined over $\mathbb R$. We have the following different notions.

1. The **real points** of $G$, ie all $x\in G$ such that $O_x/m_x = \mathbb R$
2. A **real form** on $G$, ie. the fixed points of an antilinear involution on $G$
3. A **realification** of $G$, ie. a subgroup $H$ whose complexification is $G$.

Now the definitions 2,3 are lifted straight from theory of Lie groups.

> Do definitions 2 and 3 make sense for algberaic groups? For example, what does **anti linear** mean?

> Are 1 and 2,3 equivalent?

> I'd like to see some very basic examples of a real structure on a complex algberaic group.

Comment: If by "complex algebraic group" you mean group scheme over $\Bbb C$ (with some extra adjectives), there are no real points: every point has residue field an extension of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: You're right. It should probably be defined over $\mathbb R$ in that case.

Comment: I made the edit

Comment: But then the points 2 and 3 don't make sense anymore?

Comment: It makes sense to ask if the complexification of the real points equal to the starting group? Right?